# Extracting a coordinate from a python list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a python list

```
training_data=[(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ..., (x_n, y_n)]
```

and I wish to extract a list of `x` values

```
training_data_x=[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]
```

I have tried

```
for j in range(0, len(training_data)):
    training_data_x=[i for i in training_data[j][0]]
```

and

```
training_data_x=[i for i in training_data[j][0] for j in range(0, len(training_data))]
```

but neither worked. How can I do this?

Comment: `[coord[0] for coord in training_data]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a self-documenting [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
[x for x,y in training_data]
```

Complete program:

```
training_data=[(1.5, 11), (2.5, 22), (7.5, 77)]
training_data_x = [x for x,y in training_data]
print(training_data_x)
```

Answer (score 2):

A comprehension would do:

```
training_data_x = [x[0] for x in training_data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just have a list of tuples.  I'm still a bit new to python,  but I would try :

training_data_x =[]
for i in training_data: 
    training_data_x.append(i[0])

another way you could do is create a function that takes tuple and returns the x.  Then map the function to your training_data_x variable.

Answer (score 0):

## **You should unpack them rather than iterating over:**

**Here is the code:**

training_data_x, training_data_y = list(list(zip(*training_data))[0]), list(list(zip(*training_data))[1])

Here is the walkthrough:

1. training_data gets unpacked and a zip object is created.
2. the "list(zip(..))" creates a list with x and y coordinates inside separate tuples something like [(x. coordinates), (y. Coordinates)]
3. Using indexing you extract x and y coordinates (as tuples)
4. use list to convert x and y tuples into separate lists.